# How to prevent Waf from renaming object files?

Tags: c, gcov, waf

I am using Waf to build a C project and `gcov` to have some test code coverage. However, Waf calls `gcc` in a way that produces `foo.c.1.o` from source file `foo.c` that confuses `gcov` when searching for the generated files:

```
$ gcov foo.c
$ foo.gcno:cannot open graph file
```

Fortunately, `gcov` has the `-o` option with which it is possible to specify the corresponding object file. Nevertheless, this is not convenient and executing `lcov` still fails. Therefore, my questions are:

1. Why does Waf rename the object files?
2. How can this behaviour be disabled or ...
3. How can `gcov`/`lcov` work around this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`gcovr`](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/fast/wiki/gcovr) instead of directly running `gcov`.

`gcovr` does not rely on file name magic, but parses `gcov`'s coverage files.
It then calls `gcov` with the appropriate parameters.
This works great with Waf's object file renaming.

You can run `gcovr` from Waf's `build` subdirectory:

```
cd build
gcovr --root=$(pwd) --keep
lcov --capture --directory $(pwd) --base-directory $(pwd) --output-file coverage.info
genhtml coverage.info --output-directory out
```

The `--root` option removes the current directory prefix
The `--keep` option keeps `gcov`'s temporary files, used by `lcov`/`genhtml`.

You can also use `gcovr`'s `--xml` option to produce [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)-compatible xml output.
It can then be used by various formatters (I use it with Jenkins' [Cobertura Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin))

Comment: This was really tricky to get working despite the clear answer. Apparently there's a bug in the master revision of gcovr that causes it to read each character of the --root argument as a separate path in a list. So given that $(pwd) starts with '/' it begins by searching your entire filesystem for .gcno files and hangs. I changed line 1828 where it calls get_datafiles to pass "[options.root]" instead and got it to work.

Comment: @flodin The "[options.root]" bug is fixed in gcovr 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying Waf's configuration with something like

```
bld.program(
  obj_ext  = '.o',
  source   = 'test.c',
  target   = 'test1')
```

Comment: Anyway, from Waf's F.A.Q : `Q: why does foo.cpp compile to foo.cpp.<n>.o where <n> is some number? A: else the same files might be compiled in different contexts and overwritten `

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `obj_ext` does not help. But thanks for pointing me to the unsatisfactory explanation from the FAQ (I wonder why they didn't include this important information in the Waf book).